# Infinitely scroll image inside a scroll view in android

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

So basically i have a an imageview inside a scrollview, what i want to do is be to be able to scroll infinitely without ever reaching the bottom of the scrollview.
Can this be done in any way ? the image of course will have to be repeated .. but any other method is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListView` and an `Adapter` that is modified slightly to have "infinite" scroll.The change required in your `Adapter` is something like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

The trick here is to tell it that the count is `MAX_INT`.However by doing this, it will make scroll downwards infinitely but not backwards.

In order to make the list go backwards, as in an infinite carrousel, you can trick the system by setting the default element to be something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE/2` by calling:

```
listView.setSelection( Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 );
```

By doing this, it makes the effect of infinite carrousel in both directions.I think presence of `ImageView` will not be a problem and it should work then too.Hope this helps.

**Edit**

For this, as you need to learn how to make a custom `ListView` and a `Adatper`, i suggest you to follow [this easy and short tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html).You can also download the entire project from that link.After running that project, add the above mentioned code.

Comment: can you show me how an Adapter like that is made !! i've been searching for a while .. can't seem to get any answer !!!

Comment: I have edited my answer.Please see it.And if my answer helped you please consider upvoting it.If it solved your problem then don't forget to accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: i guess that done it, will take me a lot of configuration to adjust it to my app though.
Thank you very much :)